# How do I remove all alphanumeric characters from a .NET string using the Regex class?

Tags: .net, regex

I've tried `new Regex("a-zA-Z0-9").Replace(myString, string.Empty)` but apparently that is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct regex would be `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

The regular expression `a-zA-Z0-9` matches the literal string `a-zA-Z0-9` whereas the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any of the characters in the ranges `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`.

In addition, these classes have shorthands (sort of).

- `\d` represents the class of digits, that is `[0-9]`.
- `\w` represents the class of alphanumerical characters, as well as underscore, that is `[0-9A-Za-z_]`.

Useful links:

- [Character classes on Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something simple. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Just for laughs you could also do it like this....

```
string newString = new string(s.Where(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

(much, much slower the first time through...then subsequent runs, faster)